# how to convert "number" into actual number from a huge dataset file?

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    city: "Delhi",
    lat: "28.66",
    lang: "77.23",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    city: "Mumbai",
    lat: "18.9667",
    lang: "72.8333",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    city: "Kolkata",
    lat: "22.5411",
    lang: "88.3378",
    country: "India"
  }
];
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove the quotation marks from `lat` and `lang` fields only, so they get a number data type?

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search and replace

```js
let json = `[{"1":"2","2":"1.2.3.4","city":"Delhi","lat":"28.66","lang":"77.23","country":"India"},{"city":"Mumbai","lat":"18.9667","lang":"72.8333","country":"India"},{"city":"Kolkata","lat":"22.5411","lang":"88.3378","country":"India"}]`

json = json.replace(/:"(\d+\.{1}\d+)"/g,':$1')

console.log(json)
```

Comment: Note that this may harm JSON that has keys that consist of only digits (like `{ "1": "one" }`, or that has string values that have digits and 2 or more points, like `{ "start": "10.06.2021" }`. Manipulating JSON with regular expressions is not best practice.

Comment: @trincot I agree. I fixed them however

Comment: OK, just note that you have required the point to be there, so "2" (first value) does not get converted. Also, the colon may be followed by white space. In my opinion it is better to parse JSON, and manipulate the object (which apparently the OP already had -- no JSON there).

Comment: Yeah yeah. It is only useful if useful. All other solutions were rejected by op

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` for that, and than apply the unary `+` to those two property values:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    city: "Delhi",
    lat: "28.66",
    lang: "77.23",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    city: "Mumbai",
    lat: "18.9667",
    lang: "72.8333",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    city: "Kolkata",
    lat: "22.5411",
    lang: "88.3378",
    country: "India"
  }
].map(o => ({...o, lat: +o.lat, lang: +o.lang}));
```

Comment: I am lookin for find and replace kind method , I just want to remove " " from lat and lang values from this file only ! so that i can store this into my databse because there  i have lat and lang fields as type of Number .

Comment: This is exactly what this answer is doing: it is doing a kind of "find/replace", and removes those quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

```
  module.exports = [
  {
    city: "Delhi",
    lat: "28.66",
    lang: "77.23",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    city: "Mumbai",
    lat: "18.9667",
    lang: "72.8333",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    city: "Kolkata",
    lat: "22.5411",
    lang: "88.3378",
    country: "India"
  }
].map(state => ({...state,lat: +state.lat, lang: +state.lang}))
```

Assume the file name is `data.js`

`import States from './data.js`

when you will import the file where you are writing the logic for storing it in the database, you will get the array of objects, which is having `lang` and `lat` property whose data type will be number as we have converted string to number type

Comment: I am lookin for find and replace kind method , I just want to remove " " from lat and lang values from this file only ! so that i can store this into my databse because there  i have lat and lang fields as type of Number .

Answer (score 2):

Using `+` you can convert a string to a number

you can use `for` or `Array.prototype.map`.

If you want to use a `for`:

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
 data[i].lat = +data[i].lat;
  data[i].lang = +data[i].lang;
}
```

If you want to use a `map`:

```
const result = data.map(e => ({
  ...e,
  lat: +e.lat,
  lang: +e.lang
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` over the array and change the desired props from string type into numbers:

```js
const data = [{
    city: "Delhi",
    lat: "28.66",
    lang: "77.23",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    city: "Mumbai",
    lat: "18.9667",
    lang: "72.8333",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    city: "Kolkata",
    lat: "22.5411",
    lang: "88.3378",
    country: "India"
  }
]

const numberLatLng = data.map(element => ({
  ...element,
  lat: +element.lat,
  lang: +element.lang
}))

console.log(numberLatLng)
```

Comment: This method replaces the string type with number type. Just save the result inside the DB afterwards.